# C++ Code with conditional constexpr annotations vs. ODR and linker

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

I've seen a lot of library code that uses the following pattern for C++11 / C++14 / C++17 support. I'm interested in understanding whether / why / to what extent this is okay in regards to "ODR violation" and linker issues.

I'll refer to a snippet from Howard Hinnant's Date library which is proposed for standardization recently.

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h

First we check things like `_MSC_VER` and `__cplusplus` to try to figure out what compiler and standard of C++ we are targetting (in some cases this can only be done roughly), and define some tokens to be either `constexpr` keyword, or blank.

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (!defined(__clang__) || (_MSC_VER < 1910))
// MSVC
#  if _MSC_VER < 1910
//   before VS2017
#    define CONSTDATA const
#    define CONSTCD11
#    define CONSTCD14
#    define NOEXCEPT _NOEXCEPT
#  else
//   VS2017 and later
#    define CONSTDATA constexpr const
#    define CONSTCD11 constexpr
#    define CONSTCD14 constexpr
#    define NOEXCEPT noexcept
#  endif

#elif defined(__SUNPRO_CC) && __SUNPRO_CC <= 0x5150
// Oracle Developer Studio 12.6 and earlier
#  define CONSTDATA constexpr const
#  define CONSTCD11 constexpr
#  define CONSTCD14
#  define NOEXCEPT noexcept

#elif __cplusplus >= 201402
// C++14
#  define CONSTDATA constexpr const
#  define CONSTCD11 constexpr
#  define CONSTCD14 constexpr
#  define NOEXCEPT noexcept
#else
// C++11
#  define CONSTDATA constexpr const
#  define CONSTCD11 constexpr
#  define CONSTCD14
#  define NOEXCEPT noexcept
#endif
```

Then, many member functions and such are annotated using these macros:

```
// date composition operators

CONSTCD11 year_month operator/(const year& y, const month& m) NOEXCEPT;
CONSTCD11 year_month operator/(const year& y, int          m) NOEXCEPT;

CONSTCD11 month_day operator/(const day& d, const month& m) NOEXCEPT;
CONSTCD11 month_day operator/(const day& d, int          m) NOEXCEPT;
CONSTCD11 month_day operator/(const month& m, const day& d) NOEXCEPT;
CONSTCD11 month_day operator/(const month& m, int        d) NOEXCEPT;
CONSTCD11 month_day operator/(int          m, const day& d) NOEXCEPT;

CONSTCD11 month_day_last operator/(const month& m, last_spec) NOEXCEPT;
CONSTCD11 month_day_last operator/(int          m, last_spec) NOEXCEPT;
CONSTCD11 month_day_last operator/(last_spec, const month& m) NOEXCEPT;
CONSTCD11 month_day_last operator/(last_spec, int          m) NOEXCEPT;
```

Now, let's suppose I have a program that consists of some libraries compiled at C++11 standard, and some libraries compiled at C++14 standard, and many of them include this file and use these functions.

This means that, functions marked `CONSTCD14` will be marked `constexpr` in C++14 translation units, and will not be marked `constexpr` in C++11 compilation units. Let's assume that such functions are ODR-used in both kinds of translation units.

- Does this violate the ODR?
- Is the ODR meaningless here because the standard document only refers to a single language standard and does not specify interoperability between standards?
- Does `constexpr` affect the name mangling of a function?
- Should I expect to find both C++11 and C++14 versions of such functions when the final program is linked, or should I expect that if they are inline, the linker will pick either the C++11 or C++14 versions and they will be the same if the only difference is a constexpr annotation?
- Should I expect programs like this (depending on the same library at varying language standards, where `constexpr` annotations may vary based on language standard used) to "work", and this arrangement of compiling the same headers at different language standards as a minor technical debt, or should this situation be regarded as a bug?

Answer (score 3):

The ODR is meaningless here because there is no guarantee that you can compile code with different versions of the C++ language into one binary and have it work as expected.

In addition to new language and library features, a newer version of the language will clean up some older issues, make some tweaks to support new features, deprecate other things, etc.  Some of these changes can result in code behavior changing, not compiling when it used to compile, or compiling when it didn't when compiling unmodified code with the newer version.

These sorts of changes are listed in the "Compatibility" appendix of the language specification.

Answer (score 2):

**The ODR is a guarantee of strong equivalence of entities with the same name in different TU** (Translation Units). The equivalence used by each compiler is not clear. (I don't even know if compiler writers document it.)

Some variant of the ODR applies to every multi-language program (or multiple C++ compiler object files program), if only the linker level. At that level obviously the "names" of entities aren't C++ qualified object names and C++ overloaded function signatures, but the mangled names. It's up to you to check that the ABI agree as much as necessary (if you use only global objects initialization and no polymorphic object or template between compilers, they don't have to agree on everything).

The meaning of the ODR is that any use of a name with external linkage is somewhat equivalent in any TU; *in particular the invocation of a function that is inline or template deterministically performs the operations described in the body of the function visible in the TU* (to the point of the inherent non determinism of the function code).

Answer (score 1):

My $.02:

> Does this violate the ODR?

Strictly speaking I suppose, yes, but at a practical level it probably doesn't matter, certainly with specific reference to `constexpr`.

If a function is declared as `constexpr` then the compiler is guaranteed to generate a compile-time constant so no function body ever needs to be generated and that's that.

For TUs compiled with C++11, ODR will be satisfied for all those TU's, but I would still expect the result of calling the function to be a compile-time constant anyway (because clearly the semantics haven't changed and the compiler is able to generate that constant when compiling for C++14, so why can't it here?).

To put it another way, `constexpr` doesn't say to the compiler 'compile this code as a compile-time constant' (the compiler will always do its best to do that anyway).  Instead, it says, 'tell me if you can't', and hence guarantees to consumers of whatever `constexpr` is applied to that it really is what it claims to be.

> Is the ODR meaningless here because the standard document only refers to a single language standard and does not specify interoperability between standards?

Maybe we just bent the rules a little.

> Does constexpr affect the name mangling of a function?

As a qualifier of the return value?  No.

> Should I expect to find both C++11 and C++14 versions of such functions when the final program is linked, or should I expect that if they are inline, the linker will pick either the C++11 or C++14 versions and they will be the same if the only difference is a constexpr annotation?

As I believe we have now established, there will *be* no function bodies and one would expect the compile-time constants generated by both versions to be the same.  I would also expect the generated code to be the same, since `constexpr` doesn't add anything to what the compiler has already figured out for itself.

> Should I expect programs like this (depending on the same library at varying language standards, where constexpr annotations may vary based on language standard used) to "work", and this arrangement of compiling the same headers at different language standards as a minor technical debt, or should this situation be regarded as a bug?

Given the forgoing, I would expect it to work. `-std=C++x` is more about what syntax the compiler will and won't accept than anything else (although there are obviously exceptions).  Look at at this way.  If you *couldn't* mix and match libraries in the way you describe, compiler vendors would be *very* unpopular so I imagine they put the time in to ensure that, as far as possible, you can.

And what about `noexcept`.  Well, if the compiler is just generating compile-time constants across the board then clearly none of these functions can throw, so I think we can forget about it here.

**How to test the assumptions made in this post**

Knock up some sort of test program and inspect the code at [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org) for both C++14 and C++11.  I can't do that from here because it is unusable on a tablet :(